# What is the right approach to find a function?

Tags: probability, ordinary-differential-equations, normal-distribution, partial-derivative

I want to mathematically find a function that is
1. continuous
2. approach 0 at +inf and -inf
3. does NOT approach inf at 0
4. symmetrical
5. always positive
basically i know that the answer is e^(-x^2)
which is the normal distribution equation,
but i want to find it myself,
to build a set of differential equations that upon solving will give this result
my passion for this is big,
i have been thinking about this for days
but all i got so far is
f(x) = f(-x)
df(x)/dx = -df(-x)/dx
any ideas how to approach this beast?

Comment: Maybe with "symmetrical" you mean "even".

Comment: There's all sorts of functions that satisfy your requirements, there's nothing particularly special about the function you've chosen

Comment: @bitesizebo could you name one? i can't think of any

Comment: @ChrisBorder $\frac{1}{x^2 + 1}$ for example

Comment: or also $\pi/2-\arctan x^2$

Comment: @ChrisBorder Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Your conditions are not sufficient to find out a particular family of solutions by a set of equations for example also $f(x)$ such that

- $|x|>1 \implies f(x)=\frac1{x^2}$
- $|x|\le 1 \implies f(x)=2-|x|$

satisfies the given conditions.

Comment: what is the definitiion of suffient conditions? how do i define them? when do i know that i have them?

Comment: @ChrisBorder By differential equation $f(x)$ can be obtained from $f'(x)=-2xf(x)\quad f(0)=1$. By your conditions you can find $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$ as a solution but you can find also (infinitely) many others functions.